# Pig needs store / load to work

Tags: apache-pig

I have Pig scripts which work only if I store and load a variable in the middle of the script.

My trials show that a sequence like the following will fail after the DISTINCT:

1. FOREACH
2. DISTINCT
3. GROUP
4. FOREACH
5. STORE
6. STORE

But the same will succeed if I store and then subsequently load the variable as follows:

1. FOREACH
2. DISTINCT
3. STORE
4. LOAD
5. GROUP
6. FOREACH
7. STORE

The working sequences I have is:

- foreach / join / foreach
- group / foreach
- join / foreach

Furthermore I can not simply code the store & rmf functions as the code optimization of Pig will try to skip all the steps that it believes are useless (as I store a variable and load it just afterwards on the same variable name).

Has anyone seen such a strange behaviour before?

EDIT: Unfortunately I can not paste the code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have seen this behaviour, like you said - if you are not storing the values, pig will skip it

You can write UDF that get the tuple and your variable and return only the tuple.
This way , it will process the variable since you are string the tuple.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Do you have any clue why is pig behaving this way ?

Comment: I agree with you - pig find that he doesn't really need to run this since you are not storing the result. Maybe I will dig more about it